# Android Fingerprint invalidation

Tags: android, fingerprint

I'm playing around with the [Fingerprint demo for Android](https://developer.android.com/samples/FingerprintDialog/index.html), in particular the invalidation scenarios, but need a little help to translate this into production worthy logic.

I've tested the app and get the initCipher to fail due to invalidation after adding a fingerprint, but the app has to be running and the key generated while you change the settings. This is because the demo generates a new key each time the app starts. In reality you wouldn't want to do this, but instead generate the key if doesn't exist and reuse it if it does to enforce proper invalidation whether the app is running or not.

How can you modify the app so that the key isn't generated each time, but instead a check to see if one exists first is performed, then that key loaded subsequently? Can you then remove the key once invalidated so the previous logic and enrolment cycle applies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer on my own by looking at the `KeyStore` class a bit more and modifying `initCipher()`. Not the best implementation, but good enough to test out stuff:

```
private boolean initCipher(Cipher cipher, String keyName) {
    try {
        mKeyStore.load(null);
        // ADDED: Check is keystore contains my key name
        if(!mKeyStore.containsAlias(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME)) {
            // ADDED: Create if it doesn't
            createKey(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME, true);
        }
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) mKeyStore.getKey(keyName, null);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return true;
    } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
        // ADDED: Remove the key if it is invalidated so 
        // it can be created fresh next time
        try {
            mKeyStore.deleteEntry(keyName);
        } catch (KeyStoreException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
    }
}
```

Also need to remove the `createKey()` call from `onCreate()` too obviously.